# Element-wise element reciprocal of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this.
Given a matrix 
$$
R = \begin{bmatrix}
    r_{11}  & r_{12} \\
    r_{21}  & r_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is there a matrix $T$ that gives the matrix $\hat{R}$ containing the element-wise reciprocal of the elements?

That is, is there a $T$ such that $\hat{R} = T R $?
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1/r_{11}  & 1/r_{12} \\
    1/r_{21}  & 1/r_{22}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
    t_{11}  & t_{12} \\
    t_{21}  & t_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    r_{11}  & r_{12} \\
    r_{21}  & r_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If not, is there (in linear algebra) another way in which this matrix $\hat{R}$ be obtained?

Comment: The operation isn't linear...

Comment: All I can tell you is that $\hat{R}$ is called the *Hadamard inverse* of $R$.